# How to add multi prefix

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below list:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

and like to add a prefix to each one a different IP. example:\

```
text1:127.0.0.1:11111
text2:192.168.1.1:22222
text3:127.0.0.1:11111
text4:192.168.1.1:22222
text5:127.0.0.1:11111
```

etc till the end of the list.

I've tried

```
Find: ^(.*)$
Replace: $0:127.0.0.1:11111\r\n$0:192.168.1.1:22222\r\n
```

But it giving a mess!

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done within Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: I don't see a different IP for each. I each two different IPs + ports that are appended one after the other on lines. Is this based on odd and even lines?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*:      `^(.*)(\R.*)?$`
*Replace With*: `(?2$1\:127.0.0.1\:11111$2\:192.168.1.1\:22222:$1\:127.0.0.1\:11111)`

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*)` - Group 1: the whole line
- `(\R.*)?` - Group 2 (optional): a linebreak sequence and the whole line
- `$` - end of line

Replacement:

- `(?2` - if Group 2 matches, then

  - `$1\:127.0.0.1\:11111$2\:192.168.1.1\:22222`  - Group 1 value (`$1`), then insert `:127.0.0.1:11111` substring, then Group 2 value (`$2`) and then `:192.168.1.1:22222` substring
- `:` - else

  - `$1\:127.0.0.1\:11111` - Group 1 value (`$1`) and insert `:127.0.0.1:11111` substring
- `)` - end of `if` block.

Proof:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the column editor functionality?

Considering a file with:

```
text1:
text2:
text3:
text4:
text5:
```

and some other file with

```
127.0.0.1:11111
192.168.1.1:22222
127.0.0.1:11111
192.168.1.1:22222
127.0.0.1:11111
```

1. Go to first file, and place the cursor at the beginning of the file
2. Then, press ALT + SHIFT + END, to select to the end of the line
3. Then, press ALT + SHIFT + Page Down, to select to the end of tile file
4. Now, press CONTROL+C to copy
5. Now, simply go to the second file, place yourself at the beginningand paste the content